# has_many :through - Apply a limit to the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I know I can apply a limit to the associations in a `has_many :through`, i.e.:

```
class Post
  has_many :commenters, through: :comments, uniq: true, limit: 10
end
```

This will return a maximum of 10 `commenters`. But what if I only want to know people who contributed the first 10 comments? (e.g. if there was a ping-pong comment thread, it would yield only 2 results). In other words, how do I limit the number of `comments` in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps its better to separate the relation definition from the query you want to make.

```
class Post
  has_many :commenters, through: :comments

  def last_commenters
    comments.order('created_at DESC').limit(10).map{|c|c.commenter}.uniq
  end
end
```

Disclaimer: code not tested.

Comment: You should be using a join for that.

Comment: Yes, it might not be possible with has_many syntax. @depa what do you mean by that? I notice this could probably be a faster query using something like Comment.find(comments.uniq(true).pluck(:commenter_id)) ... not sure if that's what depa is getting at.

Comment: The query I posted leaves a lot of room for improvement, I agree.